# Proving continuity preserves inequality from dense subset to entire space

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

I'm working on proving the following statement:

If ${f(x) \leq g(x)}$ in ${D}$, a dense subset of a metric space ${X}$, then ${f(x) \leq g(x)}$ for all ${x \in X}$.

I've proven a similar statement, where ${f(x)=g(x)}$ extends to all ${x \in X}$ - this proof is included below.

Let ${X}$ be a metric space with a dense subset ${D}$, and ${D'}$ denote the set of limit points of D. Assume ${f(x) = g(x)}$ for all ${x \in D\subset X}$.

Take ${x \in X}$. If ${x \in D}$, ${f(x)=g(x)}$, by assumption.

If ${x \in D'}$, then there exists a sequence ${(x_n) \subset D}$ such that ${(x_n) \rightarrow x}$. Since ${f}$ and ${g}$ are continuous on D, we have ${f(x)=lim(f(x_n))=lim(g(x_n))=g(x)}$, so ${f(x)=g(x)}$ for all ${x \in X}$.

Does this proof hold for the case with inequalities as well? I can't see why it wouldn't.

Comment: You should mention the continuity condition in the statement

Comment: Yes, the same proof will work if you replace $\lim f(x_n) = \lim g(x_n)$ with $\lim f(x_n) \le \lim g(x_n)$.